# Facebook fan page iframe share button

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-page

I just start on creating fan page on facebook. Left hand side of the fan page, there is a "Share" button which is sharing the current fan page.

I saw that it's url is: http://www.facebook.com/ajax/share_dialog.php?params

When i try to use this, it's failed. Is there any method can use this or simulate this function, allowing me to share the fan page?

Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is basically dead, but it still comes up in Google, so I figured I'd answer it.  This is possible using Jquery and the FB Javascript API.

http://fbmhell.com/2011/07/facebook-share-popup-iframe-tabs-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it doesn't allowing me to add comment, post to wall as the share button do. any other suggestion?

Comment: It does, when you click `Like` a popup appears giving you the option to share and add comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method I describe here : [How to make custom share buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753153/how-to-make-custom-share-buttons/5753384#comment-6795080)

It works in page tabs.

Comment: @Burjua Yes it does, I use it ... What does not work ? Can you give some more details ... So I can help you ??